# Passing the value of variables inside Python function under recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, global-variables

[image]

I want to enumerate the binary series generated with the code below (just copy-paste to see what I'm trying to do), I used Global var but still cannot find the way to pass the value of counters (nn,nx,ny). **Please don't mind how to make the same series in a better way**, I just want to know how to pass the value of the counters thru these recursions in order to enumerate the output as in the image at the head of this post. Thanks.

```
def ConcatenateString(saccum,nn):
    if len(saccum)<4:
        biset=[1,0]
        for a in biset:
            if a==1:
                prevstring = saccum
                newsaccum = saccum+str(a)
                nx=nn+1
                print(nx,newsaccum)
                ConcatenateString(newsaccum,nx)
            else:
                newsaccum = prevstring+str(a)
                ny=nx+1
                print(ny,newsaccum)
                ConcatenateString(newsaccum,ny)
        nn=ny
        return (nn)

##MAIN
newstring=str("")
nc=0
ConcatenateString(newstring,nc)
```

Comment: It's not 100% clear for me what youre trying to do, but if you want to pass integers to the recursion, why don't you add the integers as parameters?

Comment: @IsaacDj Yes, I did it. But the value returned is the one of the previous iteration, and not the one returned with the function.

Comment: Can you please mention what is your expected output ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate about your code, I ran the code but didnt fully understand the aim.

Comment: @MohammedKashif The result is a list with 2 columns having these results
1 1
2 11
3 111
4 1111
5 1110
6 110
7 1101
8 1100
9 10
10 101
11 1011
12 1010
13 100
14 1001
15 1000
16 0
17 01
18 011
19 0111
20 0110
21 010
22 0101
23 0100
24 00
25 001
26 0011
27 0010
28 000
29 0001
30 0000

Comment: you should get value from function ie. `nn = ConcatenateString(..., nn)`

Comment: @IsaacDj I added an image with the desired output to the head of the message. I hope is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send `nn` to function and get it back to continue counting

```
nn = ConcatenateString(newsaccum, nn)
```

---

```
def ConcatenateString(saccum,nn):
    if len(saccum)<4:
        biset=[1,0]
        for a in biset:
            if a==1:
                prevstring = saccum
                newsaccum = saccum+str(a)
                nn += 1
                print(nn, newsaccum)
                nn = ConcatenateString(newsaccum, nn)
            else:
                newsaccum = prevstring+str(a)
                nn += 1
                print(nn,newsaccum)
                nn = ConcatenateString(newsaccum, nn)
    return nn

ConcatenateString("", 0)
```

---

**EDIT:** Reduced version.

```
def ConcatenateString(saccum,nn):
    if len(saccum)<4:
        biset=[1,0]
        for a in biset:
            if a == 1:
                prevstring = saccum
                newsaccum = saccum + str(a)
            else:
                newsaccum = prevstring + str(a)
            nn += 1
            print(nn, newsaccum)
            nn = ConcatenateString(newsaccum, nn)
    return nn

ConcatenateString("", 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got stuck with same way of not doing things.

Comment: I also reduced it like that. Thanks a lot.